# Inequality $(EX)(EY) \le E(XY)$ - is it true for non-negative random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X,Y \ge 0$, is it true that $$(EX)(EY) \le E(XY)$$ 
or that 
$$(EX)(EY) \ge E(XY)$$

Believe me, I did my best to solve it. I can only show that none of these inequalities works for any $X,Y$ - however we have assumption on non-negativity...

$X$ and $Y$ are not independent (no information). When it comes to distribution no information also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither inequality is true in general, even for non-negative random variables.

For instance, if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and $Y=X$, then
$$ \mathbb{E}[XY]=\int_0^1x^2\;dx=\frac{1}{3}>\frac{1}{4}=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y] $$
which shows that the second inequality is false, while if we instead let $Y=1-X$ then
$$ \mathbb{E}[XY]=\int_0^1x(1-x)\;dx=\frac{1}{6}<\frac{1}{4}=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y] $$
which shows that the first inequality does not hold.

It's worth noting that $\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ is the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, hence can be either positive or negative in general.

Comment: Is it possible to show counterexample using only discrete variables ?

Comment: I imagine that you could probably replace the continuous uniform distributions in my answer with discrete uniform distributions on an appropriate set.

Comment: Tell me, if $X\cdot Y$ requires that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution ?

Comment: No, $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ can be computed as long as you know the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: If $Pr(X=1)=1/2$. Then also $Pr(XY=1)=1/2$  ? ?

Comment: Do you have specific $X$ and $Y$ in mind? Otherwise no, not in general.

Comment: I mean that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution

Comment: No, not necessarily.

Comment: Ok, for example when $Y$ is independent and $Pr(Y=1/3)$ then $Pr(XY=1)=Pr(X=1, Y=1)=Pr(X=1)Pr(Y=1) =1/2\cdot 1/3=1/6$ ?? My problem is that I don't exactly understand what does it mean $XY$..

Comment: $XY$ is the random variable given by evaluating $X$ and $Y$ and then multiplying the result. Remember that random variables are ultimately just functions on a probability space, so $XY$ is just the product of two functions.

Comment: Yes, but what about distribution ? I know that it is $XY(\omega)=X(\omega) \cdot Y(\omega).$. However, I don't know what does it mean $Pr(XY=k)$

Comment: This is really too substantial a topic to discuss in the comments. I recommend these notes (http://www.math.ucla.edu/~heilman/teach/170as.pdf) for a good introduction to random variables.